# Cannot start ASP.NET Core RC2 web application in IISExpress

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a new "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)" project in VS2015. It built without any issues, so I thought to give it a test run. However, when starting up, it choked and crashed with the following error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.dll
The program '[11608] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
The program '[15048] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I don't see anything else logged. I tried debugging it, and all I found out was that it broke during the `WebHostBuilder.Run()` method in `Program` class. It is part of the framework, so I wasn't able to get much further.

Note that the program runs fine when running via `dotnet run` command. Only IISExpress does not work.

How should I go about debugging this issue?

The project.json file is below. (It was generated by Visual Studio, I did not change anything.)

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc2-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

---

Update: I created a new project for the Core RTM release, and this time it worked.

Comment: Have you looked through the [common errors area](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#common-errors) in the docs?

Comment: I have the same problem... removing project.lock.json does NOT solve the issue for me... simply no debug available in VS for asp.net core rc2 at all... not ok.

Comment: scratch that... I didn't have host.UseIISIntegration(). Combine that with deleting project.lock.json and it started working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated to the RTM release of dotnet core and creating a new project using the new version worked. I guess it must be a bug.

Answer (score 8):

The other issue is that you might be running an old version of the framework. Try going to the root (`project.json`) location of your runnable project and in a `Command Prompt` type:

```
dotnet run
```

Comment: I had this and changed all the files people had problems with (I found many references). In the end, as dumb as this is, when I upgraded all my References to use 1.1.0, I didn't install the actual runtime 1.1.0 on my development machine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem as you. For me the solution was to close VS2015, delete the file `project.lock.json`  and then restart VS again. (`project.lock.json` will be generated automatically)

It looks like the debugger cannot attach to the application. In my case I added a `throw new Exception("...");` in the first line of the function `public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)` and the application just dies and doesn't break on the unhandled exception as expected.

After `project.lock.json` was rebuilt the debugger works fine again.

Comment: Removing project.lock.json helps me too.

Answer (score 0):

For those bumping into this, I had the same exactly behavior and error message as described in the question.

Apparently there are some terms that can't **solely** be used as the project name, such as `web` or `app`. (I fixed it renaming my project to `WebApp`)

It was already [logged as a bug](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/176) and the fix will be included in the upcoming releases.

Unfortunately, after the first failed run, a project rename isn't enough to make it work, since the IIS Express config file keeps the old entry.
Just edit the `applicationhost.config` file located at `[PROJECT_ROOT]\.vs\config\` and remove the `site` element that is named `web` or `app`, restart VS and run it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error when I run my project (not using IIS).
After some investigation I found out that server url in appsettings.json (which using in Configuration) was already busy. I changed url and it worked well.
Hope it helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. The solution is found was that my x64 app was set to build as x86