# Cannot start ASP.NET Core RC2 WebApplication in IISExpress

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-express, asp.net-core-1.0

I have problem with .Net Core RC2. I have project with name "App" which I can't start with IIS Express but it works fine with "dotnet run". When I create new project let say with name "WebApplication2" I can start it, but when I create new "App" again on different place, it can't be run. When I rename "App" to something new, which includes "project name","folder name", name in ".vs\config\applicationhost.config" all is going fine

I saw :

[Cannot start ASP.NET Core RC2 web application in IISExpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37329532/cannot-start-asp-net-core-rc2-web-application-in-iisexpress)

but it don't work for me. What can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in AspNetCoreModule. https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/176
The current workaround is to rename the app.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: or open the cli and write `dotnet run`